# How to fix random rectangle sprite appearing on screen in Xcode Swift game

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sprite

I am creating a sprite-kit Swift Xcode game. The game has coins in the levels and I used a method learned from an online instructor of using red color sprite boxes to add coins in them. The method worked, and now I have coins replacing the place of what used to be the red color sprite.

In the game, I added SKPhysics to every sprite in it. As soon as I ran the project, a random transparent box sprite appeared, adjacent to the position of the coins (I know because my ball bumped into it and stopped and also that white lines formed around it because I let the game show the physics on the screen).

I've tried changing the anchor point of the red box because I thought it was a problem of positioning but that didn't work. Below is the code I used for adding the coins on the screen

Where I called it (the default of a switch statement of adding physics to every special sprite depending on their name in it) :

```
switch name {
        case "Enemy":
            PhysicsHelper.addPhysicsBody(to: sprite, with: name)
        default:
            let component = name.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
            if let rows = Int(component[0]), let columns = Int(component[1]) {
                calculateGridWith(rows: rows, columns: columns, parent: sprite)
            }

    }
}
```

The functions:

```
static func calculateGridWith(rows: Int, columns: Int, parent: SKSpriteNode) {
    parent.color = UIColor.clear
    for x in 0..<columns {
        for y in 0..<rows {
            let position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            addCoin(to: parent, at: position, columns: columns)
        }
    }
}

static func addCoin(to parent: SKSpriteNode, at position: CGPoint, columns: Int) {
    let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: GameConstants.StringConstants.coinImageName)
    coin.size = CGSize(width: parent.size.width/CGFloat(columns), height: parent.size.width/CGFloat(columns))
    coin.name = GameConstants.StringConstants.coinName

    coin.position = CGPoint(x: position.x * coin.size.width + coin.size.width/2, y: position.y * coin.size.height + coin.size.height/2)

    let coinFrames = AnimationHelper.loadTextures(from: SKTextureAtlas(named: GameConstants.StringConstants.coinRotateAtlas), withName: GameConstants.StringConstants.coinPrefixKey)
    coin.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: coinFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1)))

    PhysicsHelper.addPhysicsBody(to: coin, with: GameConstants.StringConstants.coinName)

    parent.addChild(coin)
}
```

The functions for removing the coins after touching it:

```
func handleCollectible(sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    switch sprite.name! {
    case GameConstants.StringConstants.coinName:
        collectCoin(sprite: sprite)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func collectCoin(sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    coins += 1
    if let coinDust = ParticleHelper.addParticleEffect(name: GameConstants.StringConstants.coinDustEmitterKey, particlePositionRange: CGVector(dx: 5.0, dy: 5.0), position: CGPoint.zero) {
        coinDust.zPosition = GameConstants.ZPositions.objectZ
        sprite.addChild(coinDust)
        sprite.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.4), completion: {
            coinDust.removeFromParent()
            sprite.removeFromParent()
        })
    }
}
```

I've expected coins to replace the red box I drew in the SKS file. But the result is coins replacing the red box and a transparent SKPhysicsBody/sprite appearing on the screen adjacent to the coins.

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you remove the coin? And that `SKAction.repeatForever` is dangerous if you don't give it an animation key that you can stop along with the coin disappearing

Comment: @Vollan, so sorry I forgot to include the code of the removal of the coins in the game. There, I included it in the question.